# Adding variables to JSON object - D3.js live donut chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, d3.js

I am making a donut chart with live cryptocurrency values I fetch via an ajax from an API. I can manage to combine the values I get from a number of calls into one json and then plot a D3 donut with those, but **I have to also figure out a way to add a field into the json for each currency, which will have the amount of coins the users currently has**. **The point is to be able to show the user how many coins he has in value.**

It would be best if the coin amounts the user has would be stored in another json, but I am so desperate anything would do really.

The difficulty for me is that D3 itself iterates over the json and plots the chart, making it hard to multiply particular values in the json with certain other numbers (the way you would multiply a circle radius by 2 to make the circles all bigger)

I will hence attach my source code. Hopefully everything is straightforward. You can find the chart here: http://codepen.io/kvyb/pen/EZGyJL?editors=0110

```
var a = ["https://api.cryptonator.com/api/ticker/btc-usd", "https://api.cryptonator.com/api/ticker/ltc-usd", "https://api.cryptonator.com/api/ticker/eth-usd", "https://api.cryptonator.com/api/ticker/etc-usd", "https://api.cryptonator.com/api/ticker/xmr-usd", "https://api.cryptonator.com/api/ticker/icn-usd", "https://api.cryptonator.com/api/ticker/dash-usd", "https://api.cryptonator.com/api/ticker/MAID-usd", "https://api.cryptonator.com/api/ticker/omni-usd", "https://api.cryptonator.com/api/ticker/rep-usd"];

        function fetch() {
          all_data = ["{\"floor\": ["];
          for (index = 0; index < a.length; ++index) {
            $.ajax({
              url: a[index],
              dataType: "json",
              async: false,
              error: function(data) {
                console.log("--");
              },
              success: function(data) {
                all_data += JSON.stringify(data["ticker"]) + ',';
              }
            })
          }
        };

        fetch()
        all_data += "]}";
        var pos = all_data.lastIndexOf(',');
        all_data = all_data.substring(0, pos) + "" + all_data.substring(pos + 1);
        console.log(all_data)

        // CHART
        var div = d3.select("body").append("div")   
            .attr("class", "tooltip")               
            .style("opacity", 0);

        var width = 960,
          height = 500,
          radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

        var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
          .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);

        var arc = d3.arc()
          .outerRadius(radius - 10)
          .innerRadius(radius - 150);

        var pie = d3.pie()
          .sort(null)
          .value(function(d) {
            return +d.price + 50;

          });
        var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
          .attr("width", width)
          .attr("height", height)
          .append("g")
          .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

        data = JSON.parse(all_data);

        console.log(data);

        var g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
          .data(pie(data.floor))
          .enter().append("g")
          .attr("class", "arc")
          .on("mouseover", function(d) {        
                    div.transition()        
                        .duration(0)        
                        .style("opacity", .9);      
                    div .html("Price: <br>" + d.data.price + "<br/>Volume: " + d.data.volume)   
                        .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")     
                        .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");    
                    })                  
                .on("mouseout", function(d) {       
                    div.transition()        
                        .duration(0)        
                        .style("opacity", 0);   
                })
        g.append("path")
          .attr("d", arc)
          .style("fill", function(d) {
            return color(d.data.price);
          });

        g.append("text")
          .attr("transform", function(d) {
            return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";
          })
          .attr("dy", "0em")
          .attr("dx", "0em")
          .html(function(d) {
            return d.data.base;
          });

        function type(d) {
          d.price = +d.price;
          return d;
        }
```

How would you go about showing the number of certain coins a user has on hover?

Another approach, instead of adding values to json, would be to get all prices from the "all_data" variable, but if I try to iterate over the json I get "undefined" returned. I thought of maybe creating another json with only the prices from "all_data" and use that to find the portfolio number. Any help would be greatly appreciated.